# jar file with source code only

Tags: java, jar

Suggest I have a HelloWorld.jar file, this file contains only HelloWorld.java , which is the source code of the application.

Will it be possible to run this jar file and execute the application, even though I don't have HelloWorld.class?

Comment: Can you please explain why you need this?

Comment: Practicing Java and trying new things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done: [See the javax.tools api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html#package_description). It is not easy, but it can be done....

You will likely be better off with a script that unjars the file, compiles it, and runs it.

Answer (score 1):

Directly? No. `java` accepts only classfiles. To use source it must be compiled with `javac`. Nothing keeps you or a utility from compiling the source files to class files and using *those*, however.